# tcolorbox: Colored margins in breakable box

Tags: margins, page-breaking, tcolorbox

Maybe I haven't made myself clear. In the following example

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
enhanced,
breakable,
toggle left and right,
colback=white, 
rightrule=3cm,
if odd page={right skip=-3cm}{left skip=-3cm},
colframe = gray!50
}


\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum
\end{mybox}

Anyway

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

the margin of the breakable part on the second page is shifted to right, but I like it in the proper margin as in the second box on page 2

Comment: It works as expected for me, if I remove the empty lines from the `\newtcolorbox` call's argument.

Comment: [Crosspost on goLaeX](https://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,108993.html#108993)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  toggle left and right,
  colback=white, 
  rightrule=3cm,
  if odd page={right skip=-3cm}{left skip=-3cm},
  colframe = gray!50,
  extras middle and last={if odd page={right skip=-3cm}{left skip=-3cm},}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum
\end{mybox}

Anyway

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image: better behaved boxes?]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much @cfr